# chisel "Enum(UInt(), 5)" failed

Tags: scala, chisel

when I was trying to use Chisel to build an FSM, I used Enum() as the Chisel Tutorial said. However, I encountered such errors.

my code:

```
val sIdle::s1::s2::s3::s4::Nil = Enum(UInt(), 5)
```

however, when I executed *sbt run*, it printed out that

```
[error] /Users/xxx.scala:28:3: object java.lang.Enum is not a value
[error]   Enum(UInt(),5)
[error]   ^
```

My build sbt file is

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
resolvers ++= Seq(
Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
)
libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % "3.1.+"
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comment into a full answer so it's more obvious for future people.

In `chisel3`, a lot of things that were in `package Chisel` in Chisel2 were moved in to `package chisel3.util`. You can use the [ScalaDoc API](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/latest/index.html) to search for things like `Enum` or `switch` to see where they are located (and other associated documentation).

Also in chisel3, `Enum(type, size)` has been deprecated in favor if `Enum(size)`, ie. you should use:

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util.Enum

val sIdle :: s1 :: s2 :: s3 :: s4 :: Nil = Enum(5)
```

I would also like to mention we have a new "ChiselEnum" coming that provides more functionality than the existing API and we intend to extend it's functionality further. If you build chisel3 from source you can use it already, or you can wait for the release of 3.2. Example of new enum:

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.experimental.ChiselEnum

object EnumExample extends ChiselEnum {
  val e0, e1, e2 = Value // Assigns default values starting at 0

  val e100 = Value(100.U) // Can provide specific values if desired
}
import EnumExample._

val myState = Reg(EnumExample()) // Can give a register the actual type instead of just UInt
myState := e100
```

Comment: Thanks. I've successfully imported the "switch". However, note that we should import both "chisel3.utils.switch" and "chisel3.utils.SwitchContext" to enable "switch" and "chisel3.utils.is" to enable "is"

Comment: Good point, I think people generally just do `import chisel3.util._` when using `switch`

Comment: Yes, I just knew it minutes ago lol. It seems that underscore would import all objects and classes.

Answer (score 1):

By default `Enum` references `java.lang.Enum`. Chisel has its own `Enum` object, which you have to import before using:

```
import Chisel.Enum
import Chisel.UInt

val sIdle::s1::s2::s3::s4::Nil = Enum(UInt(), 5)

// Or an alternative way to unpack a List:
// val List(sIdle, s1, s2, s3, s4) = Enum(UInt(), 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! However, I've this line
   " import chisel3._ ". Shouldn't this cover the enum class?

Comment: @EricWu It seems, it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Now I encountered other problems... I could not use the argument "switch" --> not found: value switch

Comment: In chisel3, many utilities were moved into `chisel3.util`, try `import chisel3.util.Enum`. If in doubt, you can search the Chisel3 ScalaDoc: https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/latest/index.html. Note that the ScalaDoc includes package `Chisel` as a compatibility wrapper for Chisel2, you should prefer things in `chisel3`. Also note that you should import things from `chisel3.whatever` rather than `chisel3.core.whatever`

Comment: Seconding @jkoenig above, but more strongly: The `Chisel` compatibility layer should only be used if you're dealing with legacy code written in Chisel2. Any new code should always use `chisel3`.